# How to translate or replace subject terms in DSpace if I have the translations in a file

Tags: java, xslt-1.0, dspace

I would like to translate the subject(MeSH) terms displayed in item-view.xsl in the DSPace instance that I'm maintaining if the language is switched. Previously I am using the code below (I added this in `XSLUtils.java` class) to lookup to Babelmesh site and translate it on the fly.

```
    public static String lookupBabelMeSH(String term, String lang) {
    try {
        URLConnection babelMeshConn = (new URL("https://babelmesh.nlm.nih.gov/mesh_trans.php?oterm=" + URLEncoder.encode(term, "UTF-8") + "&in=ENG&out=" + lang)).openConnection();
        babelMeshConn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        babelMeshConn.setReadTimeout(5000);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(babelMeshConn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String value = in.readLine();
        in.close();

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
            return value;
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

    }

    return null;
}
```

I then used it in `item-view.xsl` like this:

```
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$active-locale!='en'">
      <xsl:variable name="current-locale">
        <xsl:if test="$active-locale='fr'">
          <xsl:text>FRE</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$active-locale='zh'">
          <xsl:text>CHN</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="translation">
        <xsl:value-of select="util:lookupBabelMeSH(node(),$current-locale)"/>
      </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$translation=''">
          <xsl:value-of select="node()"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="$translation"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="node()"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
```

Now, I would like to translate the text without calling BabelMesh site everytime the language is switched since there's a limit to the number of requests. Also, since the url to BabelMesh is hardcoded, any changes to BabelMesh service will break the rendering of the translation. I only need to translate the terms into chinese and french. I have the translations located in `[dspace]/config/mesh` directory. The files are named `mterms_fr` and `mterms_zh` for french and chinese translations respectively.

The contents of these files looked like these:

**mterms_fr**

```
Acanthocheilonemiasis::acanthocheilonemiase
Acanthocytes::ACANTHOCYTE
Acantholysis::ACANTHOLYSE
Acanthoma::ACANTHOME
Acanthopodina::ACANTHOPODINA
Acanthosis Nigricans::ACANTHOSIS NIGRICANS
Acarbose::ACARBOSE
Acari::ACARIEN
Acaricides::Acaricides
Acaridae::ACARIDAE
Acatalasia::ACATALASIE
Accelerated Idioventricular Rhythm::RYTHME IDIOVENTRICULAIRE ACCELERE
Acceleration::ACCELERATION
```

**mterms_zh**

```
Acanthocheilonemiasis::棘唇虫病
Acanthocytes::棘形红细胞
Acantholysis::皮肤棘层松解
Acanthoma::棘皮瘤
Acanthopodina::Acanthopodina
Acanthosis Nigricans::Acanthosis Nigricans
Acarbose::Acarbose
Acari::Acari
Acaricides::Acaricides
Acaridae::Acaridae
Acatalasia::Acatalasia
Accelerated Idioventricular Rhythm::Accelerated Idioventricular Rhythm
Acceleration::加速度
```

If you noticed, the `::` is the separator between the english terms and the translations. If there's no translation for that term, the english term is retained (eg `Acaricides`).

So would it be possible to just lookup to these files from the `[dspace]/config/mesh` directory and do the translation on-the-fly?

**EDIT**

I would like to add that if ever the term is not found in the translation file, it should be returned as is (eg `some random text` should return `some random text`) since it is expected that I have no control to what users will input in the subject field (ie via batch import).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this (added to XSLUtils.java):

```
        private static Properties chinnese = null;
                 private static Properties french = null;

            static{


               try {
               chinnese = new Properties();
               String mterms_zhPath=ConfigurationManager.getProperty("mterms_zh.path");
               chinnese.load(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(mterms_zhPath)), "UTF8"));
               french = new Properties();
               String mterms_frPath=ConfigurationManager.getProperty("mterms_fr.path");     
               french.load(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(mterms_frPath)), "UTF8"));
               } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (IOException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
               }
            }

            public static String lookupMeSH(String term, String lang) {
               String translated=null;
               if("zh".equals(lang)){
                   translated=chinnese.getProperty(term);
               }else if("fr".equals(lang)){
                   translated=french.getProperty(term);
               }
               return translated;
            }
```

At dspace.cfg you should add the path of files:

```
mterms_zh.path= /put/the/file/path
mterms_fr.path=/home/dspace_instalation/config/mterms_fr
```

check langs comparations and file adquisition.

then change:

```
<xsl:value-of select="util:lookupBabelMeSH(node(),$current-locale)"/>
```

for

```
<xsl:value-of select="util:lookupMeSH(node(),$current-locale)"/>
```

at the xsl

And replace the files separator from "::" to "="

ADDED full running class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Properties;


public class Test3 {
    private static Properties chinnese = null;
    private static Properties french = null;

static{

          chinnese = new Properties();
          try {
          String mterms_zhPath="D:/mterms_fr";     
          chinnese.load(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(mterms_zhPath)), "UTF8"));
          french = new Properties();
          String mterms_frPath="D:/mterms_fr";     
          french.load(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(mterms_frPath)), "UTF8"));
          } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }

        public static String lookupMeSH(String term, String lang) {
          String translated=null;
          if("zh".equals(lang)){
              translated=chinnese.getProperty(term);
          }else if("fr".equals(lang)){
              translated=french.getProperty(term);
          }
          return translated;
        }
        public static void main (String [] args) { 
          //  Test3 test3=new Test3();
            //XSLUtils s = new XSLUtils();
            System.out.println(lookupMeSH("Acari", "fr")); }
}
```

Comment: Adán, thanks for this. I'm having errors in my IDE though. Particularly in the `getClass()` portion where it says "Non static method 'getClass()' cannot be referenced from a static context". Also, how can this method locate the mesh terms? I'm actually expecting that `ConfigurationManager.propertyNames` will be used to reference the files. Please advice and thanks in advance.

Comment: I changed the code and it compile, but i dont tried it.

Comment: Hi Adán. I've added this code for testing in my IDE: `public static void main (String [] args) { XSLUtils s = new XSLUtils();System.out.println(lookupMeSH("Health", "fr")); }` I also replaced the values of `String mterms_frPath` to the absolute path of the file. When I run the code, I received this error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at org.dspace.app.xmlui.utils.XSLUtils.lookupMeSH(XSLUtils.java:145)` which is referring to this line of code: `translated=french.getProperty(term);`. It seems the contents of this file are not loaded. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: thanks for the updated code. After running multiple tests with different terms, I discovered that the code does not work for terms that have spaces (eg `Accelerated Idioventricular Rhythm`). It returned `null`.

Comment: try replacing whitespaces at terms files with \u0020. one two = value TO
one\u0020two = value

Comment: Thanks Adán. Replacing spaces with `\u0020` did indeed worked for terms with spaces. Unfortunately, this only works if I run `XSLUtils.main()` but not when I tried it on my DSpace instance. I tried using absolute paths after using `ConfigurationManager.getProperty` did not work, and it's still not working. I'm starting to doubt if this is possible. I would gladly mark your answer as the accepted answer if this will work in my DSpace instance. Perhaps there is something that I might be missing and would be very glad to hear from you. Thanks again.